# Create custom gradle plugin to analyze java source code and generate codes

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, gradle-plugin

I am trying to create a plugin to generate some java code and write back to the main source module. I was able to create a some simple pojo class using JavaPoet and write to the src/main/java.

To make this useful, it should read the code from src/maim/java folder and analyze the classes using reflection. Look for some annotation then generate some codes. Do I use the SourceTask for this case. Looked like I can only access the classes by the files. Is that possible to read the java classes as the class and using reflection analyze the class?

Comment: To me, this sounds like what you actually want to do is implement an annotation processor. Reflection only works on compiled classes, otherwise you'd have to parse that java source somehow (maybe using some library for that, never looked into it) to analyze/inspect it like you could via reflection.

Comment: @tjanu yes. The goal is to look into the code with annotations then generate some more codes using the plugin at compile time

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified what you want to do:
You'll need to implement an annotation processor. This has absolutely nothing to do with gradle, and a gradle plugin is actually the wrong way to go about this. Please look into Java Annotation Processor and come back with more questions if any come up.

Answer (score 0):

With [JavaForger](https://github.com/daanvdh/JavaForger) you can read input classes and generate sourcecode based on that. It also provides an API to insert it into existing classes or create new classes based on the input file. In contrast to JavaPoet, JavaForger has a clear separation between code to be generated and settings on where and how to insert it. An example of a template for a pojo can look like this:

```
public class ${class.name}Data {  

<#list fields as field>
  private ${field.type} ${field.name};
</#list>

<#list fields as field>
  public ${field.type} ${field.getter}() {
    return ${field.name};
  }

  public void ${field.setter}(${field.type} ${field.name}) {
    this.${field.name} = ${field.name};
  }
</#list>

}
```

The example below uses a template called "myTemplate.javat" and adds some extra settings like creating the file if it does not exist and changing the path where the file will be created from */path/* to */pathToDto/*. The the path to the input class is given to read [the class name and fields and more](https://github.com/daanvdh/JavaForger/blob/master/TemplateVariables.md).

```
JavaForgerConfiguration config = JavaForgerConfiguration.builder()
    .withTemplate("myTemplate.javat")
    .withCreateFileIfNotExists(true)
    .withMergeClassProvider(ClassProvider.fromInputClass(s -> s.replace("path", "pathToPojo")))
    .build();
JavaForger.execute(config, "MyProject/path/inputFile.java");
```

If you are looking for a framework that allows changing the code more programatticaly you can also look at [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org). With this framework you can construct an abstract syntax tree from a java class and make changes to it.